# MongoDb spring boot jpa @Aggregation _id deserialization problem

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, aggregation-framework

Below aggregation always produces _id that looks like this.
        `"_id": { "timestamp": 1675104059, "date": "2023-01-30T18:40:59.000+00:00" },`
and I need like this :
`"_id": "63d80f2ddf20b2268a986dbf"`

`@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$match': {'userId': '?0'}}","{'$project': {'allEventsOfUser': 1}}","{'$unwind': {'path': '$allEventsOfUser'}}","{'$match': {'allEventsOfUser.date': {'$gte': ?1, '$lte': ?2}}}"}) List<?> findByUserIdAndDateRange(String name, Date dateStart, Date dateEnd);`

I do not understand why the aggregation produces different result. I have tried all variants of JsonIgnore it does nothing when added to the field, nor does adding to the setter or getter. Can someone please help me, its screwing up my whole update flow, i need actual id not some funky useless object in my case.

`public class EventItem { @Id public String _id;`

it hjas something to do with aggregation but im new to mongodb and i have no idea how to stop this. Much thnx for anyone who helps!

Comment: How it is actually stored in the database?

Comment: the normal way, without being turned into an object, just "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c7a3135587511c9247db4"), as always... If you mean how is it saved, then just by using spring data jpa mongo repo save

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `id` type:

```
@Field(targetType = FieldType.STRING)
public String id;
```

I do NOT know why this breaks with `@Aggregation` annotation, there were NO problems with same api with different query like find all.